# How to display items from "Var" Data Type into ListView?

Tags: c#

How do I add the items from this Var data type (myFilesList) into the listView1?

```
        var myFilesList = allFiles.Select(f =>
        {
            using (var fs = new FileStream(f, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                return new
                {
                    FileName = f,
                    FileHash = BitConverter.ToString(SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(fs))
                };
            }
        }).GroupBy(f => f.FileHash).Select(g => new { FileHash = g.Key, Files = g.Select(z => z.FileName).ToList() })
        .SelectMany(f => f.Files.Skip(1)).ToList();
```

Comment: If your are beginner than I recommend you to not use var' instead use specyfik type.  Then you will see what type do you have and if it's the same type that method expect

Comment: What is `allFiles`?